# add column to dbf table with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbf

I have a problem when I need to add a column to table with dbf format
this is the code of adding column button event:

```
Try
        Form1.FillDataGridView("ALTER TABLE MyDBase ADD COLUMN ZipCode TEXT(10)")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
    End Try
```

error message: **operation not allowed for that type of object**

and this is the code to load dbf file in DataGridView:

```
 'OPEN CONNECTION TO dbf file
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\tunes\Documents\;Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    cn.Open()

    'Load file from dbf into DataGridView1
    FillDataGridView("select * from MyDBase ")
```

and finally FillDataGridView function:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)

    With DataGridView1
        .DataSource = dt


    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried downloading and using the [Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDB Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).

Your connection string would need to be simplified down a bit to...

```
"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\PathOnly\ToWhere\TheDataFilesExist\;"
```

Maybe its the "jet" engine driver that can not properly alter the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE MyDBase ADD COLUMN ZipCode C(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oleg, i try your syntax, but it shows another error message: Syntax error in field definition

Comment: Then try to change `C(10)` back to `TEXT(10)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Visual Foxpro installed on the computer you can do the following within your VB.net:

```
Dim VFPAlterCmd As String = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN ZipCode C(10)"
' NOTE -> "TEXT" is not a legitimate VFP Field type for this command string  

Dim oVFP = CreateObject("VisualFoxPro.Application")  
With oVFP  
   .DoCmd(***whatever VFP Commands desired (including SQL commands)***)   
   .DoCmd("USE MyTable EXCLUSIVE")
   .DoCmd(VFPAlterCmd)  
   .DoCmd("CLOSE DATABASES ALL")
End With  
oVFP.Quit()  
oVFP = Nothing
```

Good Luck